# SSRS Row number based on 2 groups

Tags: reporting-services

How to create row number based on 2 groups
My issue is 
I created new field named test to test row number and my code in next pic link

[Group based on ItemId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze8ST.png)

[but if the item duplicated the row number start duplicate also like next Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IThLm.png)

hot to create number sequence based on vendor and itemid , i need the number sequence continues with every item even it duplicated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scope. Then the runnung value will be calculated on the whole dataset or based on your grouping. For example:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!ItemId.Value, Count, "YourDatasetName")

=RunningValue(Fields!ItemId.Value, Count, "YourGroupName")
```

This gives you two different results based on the scope. And you need the second one I think.

Comment: First ex. give me same as my pic
second give me all row number is 1

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot to change the `CountDistinct` to `Count`. Because `CountDistinct` doenst count duplicates but `Count` does count everything, even duplicates.